# Is there a list of tags accessible inside playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to access an array of tags defined at execution. Is this possible?
For example:

```
ansible-playbook /dev/foo.yml --tags tag1
```

Can I read in some metadata containing value tag1 in foo.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables):

- [ansible_run_tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_run_tags)
- [ansible_skip_tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_skip_tags)

For example, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_run_tags: {{ ansible_run_tags }}
          ansible_skip_tags: {{ ansible_skip_tags }}
      run_once: true
      tags: [t1, t2, t8, t9]
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook --tags t1,t2 --skip-tags t3,t4 pb.yml
  ...
  msg: |-
    ansible_run_tags: ['t2', 't1']
    ansible_skip_tags: ['t4', 't3']
```